# Numpy linalg norm not accepting scalar when order is specified

Tags: python, numpy

Well, the title says it all:

```
from numpy import linalg as LA
import numpy as np
fortytwo = np.array(42)
LA.norm(42) # works
LA.norm(fortytwo) # works
# All the lines below raise a ValueError:
LA.norm(fortytwo,np.inf)
LA.norm(fortytwo,-np.inf)
LA.norm(fortytwo,1)
LA.norm(42,1)
```

I had to place some ugly special cases into my code to handle this. Is there a nicer way to handle this than special cases for scalar values? Why was this function written this way?

Docs don't mention it either: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html

Comment: I suppose `norm` *could* handle a scalar, and I don't know why it doesn't, but the docs *do* mention it.  The description of the parameter `x` says "Input array. If axis is None, x must be 1-D or 2-D."   A scalar is 0-D.  Instead of "ugly special cases", perhaps you could wrap the first argument in `np.atleast_1d()`.

Comment: I would understand if it behaved consistently with and without specifying order. Docs do not mention the function behaves differently when you make the order explicit. Thanks for the tip, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's part of the code (all Python and available for all to see):

```
if ord is None and axis is None:
    return sqrt(add.reduce((x.conj() * x).real, axis=None))
```

This is your case that works.

But when you specify `ord`, it looks at the dimensions.  In your case `nd==0`.

```
# Normalize the `axis` argument to a tuple.
nd = x.ndim
if axis is None:
    axis = tuple(range(nd))
elif not isinstance(axis, tuple):
    axis = (axis,)
```

Now `axis` is `()`, an empty tuple

```
if len(axis) == 1:
    # do things like .max(axis=axis):
...
elif len(axis) == 2:
    row_axis, col_axis = axis
    # multi dim. calculations
...
else:
    raise ValueError("Improper number of dimensions to norm.")
```

Here's your error - 0d array and non-default `ord`.

I guess they could have put in another case - if `0d` ignore the `ord` parameter.  Or you could do that yourself.